# Возникает ошибка python / vk_api

Tags: python

Код python

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType


def write_msg(user_id, message):
vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message})


# API-ключ созданный ранее
token = "xxx"

# Авторизуемся как сообщество
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

# Работа с сообщениями
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

# Основной цикл
for event in longpoll.listen():

# Если пришло новое сообщение
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

# Если оно имеет метку для меня( то есть бота)
if event.to_me:

# Сообщение от пользователя
request = event.text

# Каменная логика ответа
if request == "привет":
write_msg(event.user_id, "Хай")
elif request == "пока":
write_msg(event.user_id, "Пока((")
else:
write_msg(event.user_id, "Не поняла вашего ответа...")
```

Сама ошибка : vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: random_id is a required parameter
Пришлите код с исправлением и опишите в чем ошибка, заранее спасибо :3

Пробовал добавлять random_id но такой комманды нет...

```
if request == "привет":
write_msg(event.user_id, random_id, "Хай")
elif request == "пока":
write_msg(event.user_id random_id, "Пока((")
else:
write_msg(event.user_id random_id, "Не поняла вашего ответа
```

.

Comment: Что Вам непонятно из текста ошибки?

Comment: Мне понятно что нужно добавить random_id но когда я его добавляю выводит ошибку где сказанно что нельзя указать больше двух параметров. Можете пожалуйста исправить ошибку и скинуть код без ошибок.

Comment: Покажите, как Вы его добавляете. Добавьте это в вопрос.

Comment: Я добавил в вопрос. random_id не определяется... Что нужно импортировать чтобы определилось? Можете показать код с исправлением ошибки, спасибо заранее...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*>>Пробовал добавлять random_id* - Вы его добавили в вызов **Вашей** функции `write_msg`, но функция ожидает только 2 аргумента (`user_id` и `message`). Отсюда первая ошибка: Вы передаёте в функцию 3 аргумента, когда она ожидает двух.

---

*>>random_id не определяется* - правильно. Потому что Вы нигде не объявили никакого `random_id`, отсюда интерпретатор и не знает, что это такое.

---

Смотрите [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send):

> **random_id** - уникальный (в привязке к API_ID и ID отправителя) идентификатор, предназначенный для предотвращения повторной отправки одинакового сообщения. Сохраняется вместе с сообщением и доступен в истории сообщений.
>   Заданный random_id используется для проверки уникальности за всю историю сообщений, поэтому используйте большой диапазон (до int64).
>   целое число, доступен начиная с версии 5.45

Т.е. Вы должны передавать параметр `random_id` при обращении к **методу API**, а его значением должно быть любое 64-х битное целое число (насколько я помню, раньше было 32-х битное).

---

### Как сгенерировать `random_id`?

Можно воспользоваться функцией `getrandbits` из модуля `random` (предпочтительнее):

```py
random_id = random.getrandbits(64) # 64 бита
```

Можно воспользоваться функцией `get_random_id` из `vk_api.utils`, которая делает то же самое, что и первый вариант:

```py
random_id = vk_api.utils.get_random_id()
```

---

## Как передать `random_id`?

Исправьте описание функции `write_msg`, добавив в вызов метода параметр `'random_id'` со значением, полученным одним из способов, описанных выше.

Comment: Извините за наглость, но тем не менее у меня все равно ошибка, возможно я вас неправильно понял и делаю что-то не так. Объявил чему равен random_id но наверное не так его добавил в write_msg. Если можно, пришлите мне исправленный код пожалуйста... Не могу понять но выдает ошибку...

Comment: Очень хочу разобраться в этой проблеме, еще 2 дня назад код работал и не требовал random_id... Не знаю с чем это связанно но очень хочу разобраться.

Comment: `vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random.getrandbits(64)})`

Comment: Оно заработало! Спасибо вам большое) Я надеюсь не очень вас злил своими вопросами)

Comment: Есть галочка, если ответ помог.

Comment: Нажал, еще раз спасибо )

Comment: Надеюсь, Вы хоть что-нибудь поняли.

Comment: Да, я понял. Просто в python еще большого опыта нет и в vk_api тоже. Вот и такие вопросы возникают)